# Image generator ( generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes method) doesn't give live results

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image-generation

Pretty new to cocoa development and really stuck with probably a fundamental problem.

So in short, my app UI looks like a simple window with a nsslider at the bottom. What I need is to generate N images and place them, onto N nsviews in my app window.

What it does so far:

- I'm clicking on the slider (holding it) and dragging it. While I'm dragging it nothing happens to my views (pictures are not generated). When I release the slider the pictures got generated and my view get filled with them.

What I want:
- I need the views to be filled with pictures as I'm moving the slider.

**I figured out the little check box on the NSSlider properties, which is continuous, and I'm using it, but my image generator still doesn't do anything until I release the slider.**

Here is my code:

```
// slider move action
- (IBAction)sliderMove:(id)sender
{   
    [self generateProcess:[_slider floatValue];
}

// generation process
- (void) generateProcess:(Float64) startPoint
{
    // create an array of times for frames to display
    NSMutableArray *stops = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int j = 0; j < _numOfFramesToDisplay; j++)
    {
        CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(startPoint, 60000);

        [stops addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:time]];
        _currentPosition = initialTime;   // set the current position to the last frame displayed
        startPoint+=0.04; // the step between frames is 0.04sec
    }

    __block CMTime lastTime = CMTimeMake(-1, 1);
    __block int count = 0;
    [_imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:stops
                                          completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
         {
             if (CMTimeCompare(actualTime, lastTime) != 0)
             {
                 NSLog(@"new frame found");
                 lastTime = actualTime;
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"skipping");
                 return;
             }

             // place the image onto the view
             NSRect rect = CGRectMake((count+0.5) * 110, 500, 100, 100);

             NSImageView *iView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

             [iView setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
             NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image size:(NSSize){50.0,50.0}];
             [iView setImage:myImage];
             [self.windowForSheet.contentView addSubview: iView];
             [_viewsToRemove addObject:iView];
         }

         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed)
         {
             NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Canceled");
         }
         count++;
     }];
}
```

}

If you have any thoughts or ideas, please share with me, I will really appreciate it!

Thank you

Comment: Its a little bit late, but maybe it will help others.
We use a UISlider and registered our method to the UIControlEventValueChanged of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your NSSlider continuous, open your window controller's `XIB` file in Interface Builder and click on the `NSSlider`.  Then, open the Utilities area

[image: Utilities area]

select the Attributes Inspector

[image: Attributes Inspector]

and check the "Continuous" checkbox

[image: Continuous checked under Control header]

under the Control header.  Once you've done this, your `IBAction` `sliderMove:` will be called as the slider is moved rather than once the mouse is released.

Note:  Alternatively, with an

```
NSSlider *slider = //...
```

one can simply call

```
[slider setContinuous:YES];
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your long explanation, but I think you didn't read my question carefully...